# Elastic APM traces are not visible in ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, asp.net-core-5.0, elastic-apm

APM agent 1.12.1 is being used in .Net core 6 API.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOIWR.png)

this API is used by admin portal (ASP.Net MVC 5) and API portal (similar to swgger - .Net core 5 MVC).

APM agent is not installed and no related settings are present in both admin and API portal

- APM traces can be seen for API hit from admin portal
- ***APM traces are not visible for API hit from API portal***

is this the correct way of using APM for API? does .Net core MVC 5 cannot use the APM of API?

Comment: I'm sure this will be the solution, but as a first step check out this config: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/config-supportability.html#config-trace-context-ignore-sampled-false 

Set it to `true` in your .NET Core 6 API.

Does that solve the problem?

Comment: @gregkalapos it worked !! thank you